# NOT a group by expression SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, expression

```
create view top5food as
select f.FoodID,f.FoodName,SUM(o.Quantity) as "Total Food Sold"
from  FOODANDBEVERAGEORDER o,FOODANDBEVERAGE f
where o.foodid=f.foodid
group by o.foodid
order by SUM(o.Quantity) desc;
```

anything wrong with this query? there is an error ORA-00979 NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create view top5food as
select f.FoodID,f.FoodName,SUM(o.Quantity) as "Total Food Sold"
from  FOODANDBEVERAGEORDER o,FOODANDBEVERAGE f
where o.foodid=f.foodid
group by f.FoodID, f.FoodName
order by SUM(o.Quantity) desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `f.FoodName` in the select list but it is not in the `group by` clause.

Comment: that means i need to add f.FoodName  in the group by clause also ?

Comment: Yes you should add that column to the group by.